# Installing Python package with pip - "Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module."

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Tornado Python package with pip, but I get this error. I have tried upgrading Python from 2.7.7 to 2.7.14 but I still get the error. I have tried `pip install --upgrade pip` as well.

Is pip using the wrong version of Python?

```
lx@LX ~ $ python -V
Python 2.7.14
lx@LX ~ $ pip -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
lx@LX ~ $ pip install tornado
Downloading/unpacking tornado
  Downloading tornado-5.0.1.tar.gz (504kB): 504kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_lx/tornado/setup.py) egg_info for package tornado
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_lx/tornado/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
        raise ImportError("Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module. This means "
    ImportError: Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module. This means Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+ (although some distributions have backported the necessary changes to older versions).
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_lx/tornado/setup.py", line 146, in <module>

    raise ImportError("Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module. This means "

ImportError: Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module. This means Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+ (although some distributions have backported the necessary changes to older versions).

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_lx/tornado
Storing debug log for failure in /home/lx/.pip/pip.log
```

Python version

```
lx@LX ~ $ python 
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 19 2018, 20:12:34) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl
<module 'ssl' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.pyc'>
>>> quit()
lx@LX ~ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing pip again

```
lx@LX ~/Downloads $ sudo python get-pip.py
[sudo] password for lx: 
The directory '/home/lx/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/lx/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 964kB/s 
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (569kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 573kB 1.7MB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 3.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-9.0.2 setuptools-39.0.1 wheel-0.30.0
```

Now using the correct Python version

```
lx@LX ~/Downloads $ pip -V
pip 9.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```